# Finding the Lie map

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose I have a group homomorphism $\rho:SL(2,\mathbb{C})\to SO_0(3,1)$ given by $\rho(a)X=aXa^*$ and I want to see how the corresponding Lie map $L\rho$ looks like. By definition
$$
L\rho=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\rho(\exp (tX))Y\bigg|_{t=0}
$$
which is supposed be equal to $XY+YX^*$, but I fail to see how.

Comment: Hint: Use the product rule to differentiate $\exp(tX) Y \exp(tX)^*$.